# Npgsql failed to establish connection to CentOS PostgreSQL through PgPool

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, centos, npgsql, pgpool

I have a webapplication in Asp.net connecting to a separate database-server running CentOS with PostgreSQL. This setup works fine.

To increase performance on the database-server I'm trying to install and confgure PgPool-II for pooling database-connections on the CentOS server.

After the configuration I can connect to PostgreSQL with the pgpool configured port from the CentOS command line, so I assume pgpool is up and running.

When I try to connect from my webapplication to the database-server with my new pgpool port I get the following NpgdslException in the eventlog:

> Failed to establish a connection to '[ip-address of db-server]'

Some configuration files:

pgpool.conf:

```
listen_address = '*'
port = 6432
pcp_port = 9898

enable_pool_hba = true

socket_dir = '/tmp'
pcp_socket_dir = '/tmp'

backend_hostname = ''
backend_port = 5432

num_init_children = 50
max_pool = 4
connection_life_time = 120
client_idle_limit = 0

debug_level = 0
```

pool_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# Network access
host    all             all     192.168.0.0/24          md5
```

I have all the ports open in my CentOS firewall configured in /etc/sysconfig/iptables.
**So when I'm connecting to port 5432 in my webapplication everything is fine, but when I change the port to 6432, the port for pgpool) then I get the mentioned exception.**

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to make sure that pgpool is running on the right port.  This can be done easily using fuser:

```
fuser -n tcp 6432
```

If it doesn't return anything nothing is listening on your port.  In that case make sure pgpool is running:

```
ps -A | grep pgpool
```

If this only shows your grep, then your pgpool has not been started.  Please refer to your rpm information for information on how to start it.  This may involve `chkconfig` and `system`